# Confused about Carl Fredricksen Hat

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash

There is a Hat that I read about called **Carl Fredricksen**.
The details are

> **Carl Fredricksen**
>
> at least 5 upvotes from 5 different users in a UTC day with no downvotes

Yesterday I had answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318489/is-it-true-that-sorting-strings-is-on2logn/34318565#34318565) question, and had got `6` upvotes, with no downvote. Why did I not still got the hat??

---

I am attaching a screenshot to show that there were no downvotes.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't have *any* downvotes during that UTC day.  I see that you have one, so that's why you weren't awarded the hat.

Comment: But I can't see any downvote. Check the edit please.

Comment: I can see a downvote.  [It happened yesterday around 6:55PM UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1795279/haris?tab=reputation).  I never said that it was attached to *that* specific question.

Comment: Ok, I thought it meant no downvotes on that question. Its actually downvotes on any question in that day.